# I don't understand why my pop-up isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am currently working on a personal project but cannot get my modal to appear in the browser. I've tried researching it but I'm getting the same answers back that I am currently applying.

```js
const open1 = document.getElementById('open1');
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');
const close1 = document.getElementById('close1');

open1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal_container.classList.add('show');
});

close1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal_container.classList.remove('show');
});
```

```css
div.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.real45 {
    background-color: #BC6C25;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.real45:hover {
    color: black;
}

.modal {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
}

.modal h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.modal p {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal-container.show {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="real45" id="open1"> Open Me </button>
  
<div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">
  <div class="modal">
    <h1> Modals are cool </h1>
    <p> practice text </p>
    <button class="real45" id="close1"> Close Me </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please any and all suggestions are welcome I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put `pointer-events: none;` on `.modal-container`, all child nodes will also inherit that property, which disables all pointer events (clicking, dragging, hovering, etc.).

So when you attempt to close the modal by clicking the button, nothing will happen.

I've added `pointer-events: auto;` to the `.modal` so that these events work for child nodes and you are able to close the modal.

```js
const open1 = document.getElementById('open1');
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');
const close1 = document.getElementById('close1');

open1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal_container.classList.add('show');
});

close1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal_container.classList.remove('show');
});
```

```css
div.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.real45 {
  background-color: #BC6C25;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.real45:hover {
  color: black;
}

.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal p {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal-container.show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: 1;
}

#open1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="open1">open
</button>

<div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">
  <div class="modal">
    <h1> Modals are cool </h1>
    <p> practice text </p>
    <button class="real45" id="close1"> Close Me </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: However the modal won't open to begin with.

Comment: In your question, the modal will open.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add my `<script>` below my `<button>` and `<div>` tags. This is the correct way to make it work in browser.

```html
<button class="real45" id="open1"> Open Me </button>

<div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">
  <div class="modal">
    <h1> Modals are cool </h1>
    <p> practice text </p>
    <button class="real45" id="close1"> Exit </button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const open1 = document.getElementById("open1");
  const modal_container = document.getElementById("modal_container");
  const close1 = document.getElementById("close1");

  open1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal_container.classList.add("show");
  });

  close1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal_container.classList.remove("show");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me